# Snakemake: Pass all wildcards to a single shell command

Tags: snakemake

Snakemake supports generalizing rules with wildcards, like so:

```
rule conversion:
    input:
        "file_{name}.txt"
    output:
        "file_{name}.csv"
    shell:
        "python process.py {wildcards.name}"
```

Now say I have another rule like:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("file_{output_types}.csv", output_types=["A", "B"])
```

Calling the `all` rule, Snakemake will see that `conversion` can produce the requested files `file_A.csv` and `file_B.csv` (assuming the input files exist).

What ends up running are *two shell commands*:

1. `python process.py A`
2. `python process.py B`

**Is it possible to run just a single shell command using wildcards?**

What I would like to happen is to use the wildcards to run the command:

```
python process.py A B
```

(In my use-case, `process.py` has a long spin-up, so I want to avoid running it multiple times in a row.)

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
names = ['A', 'B']

rule conversion:
    input:
        expand("file_{output_types}.txt", output_types= names),
    output:
        expand("file_{output_types}.csv", output_types= names),
    params:
        names= names,
    shell:
        "python process.py {params.names}"
```