# How to merge multiple wildcards into a single shell command?

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I am trying to use snakemake to automate some stuff we did by hand so far.
I have one issue, where I want to call a script that has many possible output files. A minimal non-working example is this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{year}.txt", year=["15","16","17"]),

rule make_file:
    output:
       "{year}.txt",
    run:
        year_list = wildcards.year
        shell("python make_txt.py  --year {year_list}")
```

Where make_txt.py is just:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser =  ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--year', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
for year in args.year:
    with open(f"{year}.txt",'w') as f:
        pass
```

This script can take lists as arguments and then produce multiple files, one per wildcard. But it can also take a list and then do it all in one run. What I want is snakemake to call make_file only once and execute `python make_txt.py --year 15 16 17`. I need this because the real code I use is written in a way that it loops over the wildcards, and takes a lot of setup before that, so running the jobs one by one is a huge waste of time.

I tried to get some kind of parsing running in the params, and I think this is probably the way to go. Is there something I am missing?
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71503348/snakemake-pass-all-wildcards-to-a-single-shell-command) is pretty much what I am also want.
Implementing the solution from there my snakefile is:

```
years = ["15","16","17"]
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{year}.txt", year=years),

rule make_file:
    output:
       expand("{year}.txt",year=years),
    params:
        years = years,
    shell:
        "python make_txt.py  --year {params.years}"
```

calling rule all now correctly runs a single job that creates the three files. However I lose the ability to use wildcards, which I very much still want to do. My real code has many parameters, and "hardcoding" them like this, I would need to change the snakefile every time I want a different subset of the output files instead of just adjusting the target via wildcards.
Ideal would be something like giving a list as a wildcard, somewhat like `snakemake [16,17,18].txt`
which then would be interpreted as `wildcards.year = 15 16 17`. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with files but maybe with a [config option or file](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html):

```
# config.yaml
years:
  - 15
  - 16
  - 17

# Snakefile
configfile: "config.yaml"
if isinstance(config['years'], list):
    years = config['years']
else:
    years = config['years'].split(',')
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{year}.txt", year=years),

rule make_file:
    output:
       expand("{year}.txt",year=years),
    params:
        years = years,
    shell:
        "python make_txt.py  --year {params.years}"
```

Then you can customize your execution by adjusting the config.yaml contents or with `snakemake --config years=10,11,12`.

The problem with passing in filenames is that snakemake treats files special and there isn't any syntax to say "this rule will create all the years that you need" without changing another variable.  You could use a checkpoint, but eventually you need to say what a rule will produce and using a config variable is the easiest interface.